# jest with babel v7 throwing errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jestjs, next.js

I have following jest setup

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "7.0.0-beta.53",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "babel-jest": "23.4.0",
    "enzyme": "3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.3.4",
    "flow-bin": "0.76.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.4.1",
    "jest-styled-components": "5.0.1",
  }
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['.next/', 'node_modules/'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/enzyme.config.js'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/file.js',
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
};
```

**enzyme.config.js**

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

**.babelrc (using next.js v6)**

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["next/babel", { "preset-env": { "modules": "commonjs" } }]],
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"]
    },
    "development": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"],
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"],
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"]
    }
  }
}
```

And when I run event the simplest tests I get a lot of errors that could be related to react not being parsed I guess, but it should be via babel? It works in dev mode when I am working on my app.

Examples of errors I keep getting

> ```
> SyntaxError: /__tests__/ImageAvatar.test.js:
> ```
>
> Unexpected token (12:30)
>
> ```
>   10 | describe('<ImageAvatar />', () => {
>   11 |   it('Renders correctly', () => {
> > 12 |     const component = shallow(<ImageAvatar src={src} alt={alt} />);
>
>
> /__tests__/Colour.test.js:1
> ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import
> ```
>
> Colour from '../styleguide/lib/Colour';
>                                                                                                       ^^^^^^
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> ```